# C#: EF corresponding way to save data temporary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

With Entity Framework you can use lambda expression to get data etc. However, I don't wish to save anything in database, but I want its function(*save, read with lambda expression*) to pick and read data temporary till application is closed.

```
namespace Shop.Models {
    public class DemoContext : DbContext{

        public DbSet<Product> Items { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
 DemoContext context = new DemoContext();

//method{
     context.Carts.Add(cartItem);

     context.SaveChanges();
```

I tried this way but it gave me the error:

> The model backing the 'DemoContext' context has changed since the
>   database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update
>   the database

Is it possible to do something corresponding like this without involving any database?

Comment: You need to create an object to hold the data temporarily.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with saving data temporarily in an EF-mapped object.  It means that you've updated the entity model in code without migrating those changes to the database.  Take a look at EF code-first migrations.

Comment: @DVK I don't understand, I haven't updated any model intentionally. I don't use code-first, I use database first. I got the error at the line `return return db.Carts.ToList();`.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake Can you give an example? I want to save somewhere where I can access it later in other methods, like the way you handle database like EF.

Comment: I think you want a `List<Product> InMemoryItems` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interface that allows retrieval of the data, acting as a DataAccess (extending from IDbContext) and move the DbContext into it's implementation. However, for your testing, you can use a mock data access to return data without interacting with the database.

Comment: Could you give an example with code? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: The OP seems to not understand how to manage the data in memory, creating a new interface to wrap EF, using Injection, seems to be out of reach.